# Drawing smiley using javascript and showing in semi transparent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I have created code pan fiddle to show welcome message on my homepage.

I want to show `semitransparent attractive div with welcome smiley`. It should appear for 15 second and then disappear automatically.

Fiddle: [Link to Codepan](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/yAvxp)

problem:

1. Smiley style appears in sad expression. I changed radius and other parameter but does not show welcome or smiling smiley
2. Welcome message should appear beside smiley. Right now it goes below smaily //  clear:both does not help
3. Entire div should be transparent like water color. Changing and trying various color does not give it
4. Entire div should disappear after 15 second of page load, but it happens at every 1 second.

   ```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#d1').fadeOut();
    $('#d1').val='';
   },150000);
   ```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this , the smiley face with a welcome message will fadein after 15 secs of page load

**HTML**

```
<div id="d1" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:white">
  <div id="mydiv" style="display:none">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <canvas id="myDrawing" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #EEE">
          </canvas> 
        </td>
        <td>
          <p style="position:absolute; background-color:rgba(255,0,255,0.5);; filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:.5; padding:5px">
           welcome to xyz.com! 
           Please review the site and give your valuable feedback.
         </p>
       </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//var canvas = document.getElementById("myDrawing");
var a_canvas = document.getElementById("myDrawing");
var context = a_canvas.getContext("2d");
// Draw the face
context.fillStyle = "yellow";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(95, 85, 40, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = "black";
// Draw the left eye
context.beginPath();
context.arc(75, 75, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
// Draw the right eye
context.beginPath();
context.arc(114, 75, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
// Draw the mouth
context.beginPath();
context.arc(95, 95, 17, Math.PI , 2*Math.PI,true);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
// Write "Hello, World!"
context.font = "20px Garamond";
context.fillText("welcome to xyz.com! ",15,175);
$( "#mydiv" ).fadeIn( 15000, function() {
$( "#myDrawing" ).fadeIn( 15000 );
});

});
```

Working   [Fiddle-play around](http://jsfiddle.net/bharath91/X9gmr/3/)

Comment: thanks, can you please tell me  how to show welcome message beside the smile on right hand side

Comment: @Karimkhan I didnt get you , `beside the smile on right hand side`

Comment: My welcome message to little large. Also want to show few instructions in bullated form in that. So I want to show that text on right side of smiley. Did you get it now?

Comment: @Karimkhan I updated the `answer` and `fiddle` as per your requirement , check it

Comment: thanks for your effort. Here I edited as per my need. I appreciate if you help me to appear circle in center of canvas and text in top of` <td>`. rather it appears in bottom/downward http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/oEqFx

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript .setInterval() function to do this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  window.setInterval(function(){
     $( "#d1" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
       //Do things when Animation is complete.
      }); 
  },15000);
});
```